# Merge two arrays based on a common ID

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios

```
let members=[{id:3, seal:'XXXXX', name:'Test'}, {}, {}]
axios.get("xxx" + seal + "/xx")
 .then(response => {
  this.articleStream = this.members.forEach(item => {
  response.data.map(i => (i.user_id = item.id));
 });
})
```

on axios call the articleStream array needs to check the `user_id` with `id` in `members` array and `seal` which is sent during the axios call, and map the `name` from `members` to `articleStream`. But currently it is not sending the right array.

The array got back from axios call looks like below:

```
[{ id: 5, user_id: 3},{}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let members=[{id:3, seal:'XXXXX', name:'Test'}, {}, {}]
axios.get("xxx" + seal + "/xx")
 .then(response => {
  this.articleStream = this.members.forEach(item => {
  response.data.map(i => {
   if (i.user_id === item.id)) i.name = item.name;
  };
 });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you are looking for something like this:

```
axios.get("xxx" + seal + "/xx")
.then(response => {
    this.articleStream = this.members.forEach(item => {
    response.data.map(i => {
      if(i.user_id == item.id){
        return [...i, item.name]
      }
    });
  });
})
```

This would add the name of the user on each article where the user id and article user-id matches

if you want to merge all data between the arrays change following:`return [...i, item.name]`
to  `return [...i, ...item]`
in the above example